# how to load js and css file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a hard time loading css and js files with nodejs, here is what i have so far

The Js

```js
/** Install nodeJs server the easy way
 *
 *  $ npm install http-server -g     // install http server *  globally
 *  $ cd MyApp                       // navigate to the app's root folder
 *  $ http-server                    //run the server
 *
**/

console.log("Welcome to sandy server");
//Module requires
var http = require("http"),   //load http node module
 fs = require("fs"),       //load file system
 path = require('path'),
 url = require('url'),
    data = require('./data'); //load file index.js in sub-folder data
    
    
//Object "MIMETYPES"
var MIMETYPES = {
  html: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
  jpeg: "image/jpeg",
  jpg: "image/jpeg",
  png: "image/png",
  js: "text/javascript",
  css: "text/css"
 },
 PORT = 8080;


http.createServer(function (request, response){ //Returns a new instance of http.Server.
    console.log("request well recieved",request.url);
 var listener = function (error, contentType){
     if(error){
          console.log('DIE!', error);
          if(contentType !== "undefined"){
           response.writeHeader(500, {"Content-Type": contentType});
          }else{
           response.writeHeader(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}); 
          }
          response.end("<h1>FS READ FILE ERROR: Internal Server Error!</h1>");    
        }
    };
    
    var fileArray = request.url.split('.', 2),
        filenameExtension = fileArray[1];
    
    
    if( MIMETYPES.hasOwnProperty(filenameExtension) ){
     console.log("MIMETYPES::: ",MIMETYPES[filenameExtension]);
        fs.readFile(request.url, function (error, fileContent){
         listener(error,MIMETYPES[filenameExtension]);
         response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': MIMETYPES[filenameExtension]});
         response.write(fileContent);
   response.end(); 
  });
    }
    else{
     console.log("::: Not in MIMETYPES ::: ");
     fs.readFile("./spa.html", function (error, fileContent){
      listener(error);
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': MIMETYPES["html"]});
   response.write(fileContent);
   response.end();      
     });
  
    }
 console.log("end of the request");
}).listen(PORT, '127.0.0.1');//run the server on port
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:" + PORT + "/  see you next time!");
```

terminal

[image]

Chrome console

[image]

[image]

[image]

can anybody help me on that or tell me what i am doing wrong ?
i just want to use nodejs not express or something thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to open files using root location. `request.url` returns `/css/init.css` and you are reading a file from the same location. Prepend it with `.` or resolve the relative path from your script location.